# Any Win32 APIs to get the screenshots?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, screenshot, windows

I am writing an app, which needs to take the screen shots automatically (just like pressing PrintScreen button). So please suggest me how to get this done. A raw 24 bit BMP image would suffice.

PLEASE NOTE: My app is in C, so any win32 APIs that can be called from my code is what I am looking for.

(Sometimes back I had got an example code from codeproject which used to get the screen shots but the mouse pointer user to blink when the screen shot is taken. As multiple shots are taken this looks irritating to the user, so I don't want the mouse pointer to blink!)